# When my PC starts. The system go directly to the workspace, instead to go to the login screen

Tags: login, login-screen, workspaces, auto-login

I had one problem in my PC much time before this happen, my PC was formatted and the Ubuntu system was reinstalled by computer mechanic, now my PC work normally, but, when my PC start, happen the system go only to the workspace, that is bad, because somebody can access my person workspace without know my password. Does somebody know to enable the login screen to appear during the system starting, or the automatic login screen? Whatever.

Comment: It's usual to indicate what steps you have already taken before posting a question. https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-automatic-logon/

Comment: Ok, I don't find this option, can be because of Ubuntu version are different. You or somebody can to find or talk another solution that can be made on terminal too

Comment: What version then?

Comment: Version 20.04 LTS. But, please wait When I am offline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With the graphical interface**

In "Settings", go to the "Users" tab. In the top right corner of the dialog, you first need to hit "unlock" and enter your user password, because changing the setting can only be performed by a user that has administrator privileges (sudo rights). After unlocking the settings, you can change the slider next to "Automatic login" to off. Next time you boot the computer, you will see the login screen first.

If you do not have administrator privileges on that computer, you will need to ask a user that has (i.e., a user with administrator rights) to change this setting for you.

**Using the terminal**
Open the configuration file "/etc/gdm3/custom.conf" in a text editor with root priviledges:

```
sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Comment the lines that allow a user to automatically log in out by placing a comment mark `#` in front of the line, so it looks like

```
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1
```

After AutomaticLogin, you will find the actual login of your user rather than `user1`. You may also delete these lines.

Comment: Thanks, but, do you know how to do the user to be an administrator user? Because I don't know How to do; or you can answer: do you know if it has an option equivalent on terminal?

Comment: First user created when installing the system has administrator power, so can unlock that screen with his/her normal user password. See additions for how to do this from the terminal.

Comment: Ok, too bad I have I only have an administrator user When I install the system with correct configuration. I think better I resolve this problem on terminal, because the command sudo can be very useful for this problem

Comment: Thanks for help, really resolve the problem in the terminal is more effective, I mean, this helped me to resolve the problem. I don't know why only add one character resolved the problem, because in Automatic Login, the value was user instead of user1, very strange, but, resolved the problem the same so, thanks